# CD command on CMD doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

This is the screenshot of my command prompt:

[image]

Comment: Well, the command does work, it changes the current directory of drive `D:` to its root directory; it just doesn't change the current drive...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use option `/d` to change the current directory of the drive and change to that drive.
Or you can type the drive letter (`c:` in this example) to change to the drive.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.706]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\foo>cd /d d:\

d:\>cd c:\Users\foo

d:\>c:

c:\Users\foo>
```

Comment: I forgot about `cd /d`, which is a better answer than mine, so I have deleted mine, though I did add a note that `pushd` changes directory and drive, as well as allowing `popd` to return to the original directory.