# CMD won't switch from c: to d:

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, dell-optiplex

My dad's Dell Optiplex 9010 has Windows 10 as his operating system. He said it was acting weird so he restarted it. When it rebooted, it came up with the error message bad_system_config_info. It then restarts, tries to repair itself, then brings up the options to restart or advanced options. I looked up a YouTube video (because I know nothing about software) and he goes into the command prompt, and switches from c: to d:. When I try to do the same, it says "The device is not ready." Like I've said, I have no idea what I'm doing. I read that it's because the CD drive isn't active. I tried putting a random CD in but it didn't work. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong!
EDITED TO ADD: My dad bought a USB drive by EZALINK with windows 10 loaded on it, but it can also be used to boot the system so we can access the internet.
EDITED TO ADD: I tried the CD prompt listed in the comments, but it still says "The device is not ready". Please dont get this question closed by saying it's a duplicate. All the command prompts that have been suggested are not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CD command on CMD doesn't work](https://superuser.com/questions/1427935/cd-command-on-cmd-doesnt-work)

Comment: At this point it would be wise to backup important files, just in case. Sounds like Windows is corrupt. My advice would be to reinstall Windows completely, but you will loose your files.

Comment: It still says the device is not ready.

Comment: I do not know how to back up the files. My dad just informed me that he has no important files on the computer that he will miss. He bought a USB from EZALINK with windows 10 loaded on it. I was trying to see if I could fix it without resorting to completely reinstalling windows, but I guess that's what we'll have to do. Does anyone know how to reinstall from the troubleshooting options? I cannot boot windows at all past the troubleshooting screen.

Comment: "He bought a USB from EZALINK with windows 10 loaded on it" - Windows installation disk should be 100% free.  Did he purchase a disk or a Windows 10 license?

Comment: **Do _not_ use that USB to install Windows**... If you want to reinstall, download the install ISO [directly from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).  You can either let the Windows Media Creation tool create a bootable USB drive, or you can select to download the ISO and use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create a bootable USB.

Comment: Okay I misheard him. The USB has Windows 10 on it, but it is also used to boot the system so we can get on the internet to try to reinstall windows.

Answer (score 0):

The `BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO` BSOD is generally displayed due to BCD store corruption.  To resolve:

- At the WinRE command prompt *(what you're currently booted to)*, issue the following commands:

  1. `bootrec /fixmbr`
  2. BIOS *only* (i.e. non-UEFI): `bootrec /fixboot`
  3. `bootrec /rebuildbcd`

     - If it finds a Windows install, press **<kbd>Y</kbd>**, but if it doesn't, that's fine too.
  4. Reboot by closing the command terminal

*If that doesn't fix the issue, please leave a comment and I'll add to the answer, as I don't want to list multiple troubleshooting steps if you don't need them*

---

I only know of two other things that can resolve this BSOD if Automatic Startup Repair failed to, but first, just to ensure this isn't filesystem corruption, check the drive for errors:

- `chkdsk c: /offlinescanandfix`

  - *Where `c:` is the partition Windows is installed to*

If `chkdsk` identifies and fixes any issues, reboot, then re-run the `bootrec` commands above, otherwise:

- **System Restore:** From the WinRE command terminal, issue: `rstrui.exe`

  - *Due to the way in which Microsoft changed how auto restore points are created in Windows 10, there may be no recent restore points you can restore to.*
- **Restore the Registry** from the backup Windows maintains, then reboot:

  ```powershell
  # Where C: is the drive letter for the partition Windows is installed to 
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Backup the current system registry stores:
      ren C:\Windows\System32\config\DEFAULT DEFAULT.old
      ren C:\Windows\System32\config\SAM SAM.old
      ren C:\Windows\System32\config\SECURITY SECURITY.old
      ren C:\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE SOFTWARE.old
      ren C:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM SYSTEM.old

    # Copy over the backups:
      copy C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\DEFAULT C:\Windows\System32\config\
      copy C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\SAM C:\Windows\System32\config\
      copy C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\SECURITY C:\Windows\System32\config\
      copy C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\SYSTEM C:\Windows\System32\config\
      copy C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\SOFTWARE C:\Windows\System32\config\
  ```

  - *Microsoft disabled the system registry backup feature in an update a few months back, so these backups may no longer exist on your PC*

If these don't work, [reinstalling Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) will likely be the only option left.

Comment: I tried this. It says total identified windows installations: 0

Comment: I close the command prompt and it didnt do anything

Comment: @KatySteinhauer What happens when you reboot afterward?  If you're booted to WinRE _(blue background with a single command prompt terminal)_, closing the terminal will bring you back to the Advanced Startup GUI options screen, with the first option on the left being to _"Continue to Windows 10"_ (something to that effect) and selecting it will reboot the PC.

Comment: It did the same thing when rebooted. It showed bad_system_config_info, tried to repair, then says your PC did not start correctly, with "restart" and "advanced options" as much only options.

Comment: @KatySteinhauer I just added some additional steps you can try, however it depends on how much time you want to exert on trying to fix this versus reinstalling Windows, as there's no guarantee the three things I've added will fix the issue, and if they don't, you'll likely have to reinstall anyway.

Comment: I appreciate it. Can you tell me how I can go about reinstalling windows?

Comment: @KatySteinhauer Use the Windows Media Creation Tool _(link in answer)_ to create an install USB, boot from the USB, and follow the GUI prompts _(at the license key, select Skip, as Windows will activate upon running Windows Update)_.  Format the boot partition _(it's ~300MB - ~512MB in size)_, and if there is data that needs to be saved on the PC, select the partition Windows is currently installed to for the re-install _(this will place the old install within a directory called `C:\Windows.old`)_, but if there's no data you want to save, format the system & boot partitions before installing.

Comment: @KatySteinhauer Once OOBE finishes and you're at the Windows desktop, download the CPU drivers _(chipset, IMEI, possibly thermal)_ from the PC manufacturer's website _(motherboard manufacturer if the motherboard was purchased separately or upgraded after purchasing)_, install the CPU drivers **_first_**, then run Windows Update, which will install all other system drivers _(it will install all but the CPU-related drivers, which should be installed first)_.  Re-run Windows Update until no more updates are found and reboot whenever it states it needs to.

Comment: From the menus I have, I cant figure out how to boot from the USB

Comment: @KatySteinhauer  When you first turn on the laptop, the Dell logo will appear after POST - press `F12` to load the BIOS/UEFI boot menu and select the USB drive from the list.